# EasyOCR not recognizing dot and "y" for x and y values

Tags: easyocr

Easyocr is not recognizing the x and y values consistently. I have mutiple images which contains same text in images. But I am not getting consistent results having similar text box in all images.

[image: sample image]

```
img_path = os.path.join(path, filename)    
    
# Set the OCR language to use
#reader = easyocr.Reader(['en']) 
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'],gpu = False)
    
# Read text from an image
#imageData = reader.readtext(img_path,paragraph=True)
imageData = reader.readtext(img_path)
```